# After Insert Update Trigger PL/SQL

Tags: plsql, triggers, oracle11g

I have a table as `Student` and there is a `varchar` type column as `status`. i need to set value to this `status` column `after insert or update` process on this table. i have tried to write a `Trigger` for this. but i cant use as `:new.status`. it gives `Error: ORA-04084: cannot change NEW values for this trigger type`. how could i do this?

**My Code**

```
create or replace
TRIGGER STUDENT_AIU_TRI 
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON STUDENT
FOR EACH ROW 
DECLARE

v_status VARCHAR2(2);

BEGIN


  v_status := '1';

  select v_status into :NEW.status from dual;
END;
```

Comment: @Bohemian i have updated my post and added my code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to change the value in a column, you'd need to use a `BEFORE INSER OR UPDATET` trigger, not an `AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE` trigger.  Why do you believe that you need to use an `AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE` trigger?

You also don't need the local variable or to `SELECT` from dual

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trigger_name
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON student
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  :new.status := '1';
END;
```

Comment: isn't `BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE trigger` fall me in to any problem in rollback ? because in this case value of `status ` column set before insert or update other columns in that record. in any case of roll back, isn't it fall me into any problem ?

Comment: @Bishan - I'm not sure I understand the question you're asking.  The changes that a trigger makes, whether it is a before statement, an after statement, or a before or after row-level trigger, are part of the overarching transaction.  They will be rolled back if the transaction is rolled back.